# How to access generic type property in dynamic interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to access dynamic T property in an interface to extend his typing to allow this kind of generic function:

```
type AnotherType<T extends {}> = T & {
    prop: boolean;
    prop2: string;
};

interface SpecialInterface<T> {
    someProperty: AnotherType<{T["someProperty"]}>; // I know what key of T I want to extends but can't understand how
}

const func = <T extends SpecialInterface<T>>(prop: T) => {
    const a = prop.someProperty.prop; // I would like no error on this
    // somethings
}
```

I use this for now, it works but I don't like the any typing allowing everything on the function prop:

```
interface SpecialInterface<T> {
    someProperty: AnotherType<{[key: string]: any}>;
}
```

Example of prop send to func :

```
interface IProp {
    someProperty: AnotherType<{prop3: number}>
}

const prop: IProp = {
    someProperty: {
        prop: true,
        prop2: "test",
        prop3 : 5
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to limit the type of the prop object send to func to access ` prop.someProperty.prop` in my function while allowing additional properties to be send via prop.someProperty.

@alex2007v I added additional info in the question

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you

```
interface Another {
    key: number;
    value: string;
}

interface ExtraAnother extends Another {
    someProperty: number;
}

interface SpecialInterface<T extends Another> {
    someProperty: T
};

const func = (prop: SpecialInterface<ExtraAnother>) => {
    const a = prop.someProperty; // I would like no error on this
    // somethings
};
```

Comment: This is not what I need :(, ExtraAnother needs to be dynamic because I would like to send different implementation of someProperty (I added details in my questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generic constraint `T extends Record<"someProperty", any>` to ensure, 
that `T` has property `someProperty` ([`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) is a built-in type).

```
//                           v  add this constraint
interface SpecialInterface<T extends Record<"someProperty", any>> {
    someProperty: AnotherType<T["someProperty"]> // works
}

const func = <T extends SpecialInterface<T>>(prop: T) => {
    const a = prop.someProperty.prop; // works
}
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdge2ACwgJwCrggHg1CAD2AjgBMBnKAbwF8A%20KAXinwDIaAoKHqMNBGABcUAEYIEAGwgBDOAG5uvfoIBMIisDQBLOAHNFtRZ10k0AMxkBjaAGVIV7TMkBJOGcs28BYqUpQAJQgrBDQyHAAiCgQAWwgABQFINFAIgBooORB6RmolHmi4xMF0UBF4JFRMbDwAbSjYhKTSkAiAXUYAek6oAHdQgGsKTlpOThC4TShzAFc4K2YobyIScip7YKdXd3RPXAwcgAoVYVYASmZc-KgJqZlFk4A6QqaSlJBHk-kobr7B4dGJh2Fms0BcxTAXF4UBeEJa5UQKHQWEgOGofCSAGYRHAZjFROgoAwRmNbsAMYIROCkos8tDYc13iI6dDlEkRFoZhA0tdoSd1FAIiRNOleWzBNioABWa6jWhAA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However isn't this the same as typing AnotherType with `[key:string]: any` like in the example? I wanted to know if I could use the type of someproperty FROM the dynamic type :(

Comment: `AnotherType<T["someProperty"]>` is a stronger type than `AnotherType<{[key: string]: any}>`. E.g. [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=33&pln=11&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdge2ACwgJwCrggHg1CAD2AjgBMBnKAbwF8A+KAXinwDIaAoKHqMNBGABcUAEYIEAGwgBDOAG5uvfoIBMIisDQBLOAHNFtRZ10k0AMxkBjaAGVIV7TMkBJOGcs28BYqUpQAJQgrBDQyHAAiCgQAWwgABQFINFAIgBooORB6RmolHmi4xMF0UBF4JFRMbBxqKABtAGsIEA0tXT0AXREsqAZOWk5OELhNKHMAVzgrZihvIhJyKntgp1d3dE9cDByAChVhVgBKZlz8qBGxmVmDgDpChKTSkFuVGQoyczB5KAB6X6gEzAYAoFFutwGQA) would be acceptable with  an index signature, but not with above.

Comment: If that doesn't help, maybe you could elaborate a bit more in the question, what you are trying to achieve.